# How to change toggle button dark mode smoothly

Tags: javascript, html, css

I made a toggle button for dark mode, it is working good.
I want the switching between the dark mode and back going smoothly, How can I fix this?

`<button onclick="myFunction()">Toggle dark mode</button>`

```
function myFunction() {
    var elements = document.querySelectorAll(".one, .three, .five");
    elements.forEach(function (element) {
        element.classList.toggle("dark-mode");
        if (element.classList.contains("dark-mode")) {
```

/*the rest of code is just color and background settings*/

I tryed to search for the answer on stackoverflow but couldn't find any answer.

Comment: Have you tried using [transitions](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp)?

Answer (score 0):

```
.one,
.three,
.five{
    transition:color 500ms,background-color 500ms,border 500ms;
}
```

I think this should do the trick

Comment: It worked. I have added 2 images. but the transition I couldn't setup for the images. here is the code, how can I give them also transition?             else if (element.classList.contains("three")) {
                var lightsOff = document.querySelector("#lights-off");
                var lightsOn = document.querySelector("#lights-on");
                lightsOff.style.display = "block";
                lightsOn.style.display = "none";
            }

Answer (score 0):

To add a transition in this JS code, you need to define the CSS properties that are to be animated and the duration of the transition. For example:

In this example, we are defining a transition for the `background-color` property with a duration of 0.5s and an `ease-in-out` easing function.

```js
function myFunction() {
    var elements = document.querySelectorAll(".one, .three, .five");
    elements.forEach(function (element) {
        element.classList.toggle("dark-mode");
        if (element.classList.contains("dark-mode")) {
            element.style.transition = "background-color 0.5s ease-in-out";
        } else {
            element.style.transition = "background-color 0.5s ease-in-out";
        }
       
       /*continuous js code*/
```

Please enter more on your code to get more help.

Comment: It worked. I have added 2 images. but the transition I couldn't setup for the images. here is the code, how can I give them also transition? else if (element.classList.contains("three")) { var lightsOff = document.querySelector("#lights-off"); var lightsOn = document.querySelector("#lights-on"); lightsOff.style.display = "block"; lightsOn.style.display = "none"; }

Comment: there are many ways to achieve it, please implement the question with a link to jsfiddle or codepen to see the full code, I could help you better!

Comment: Try something like this:
function myFunction(){if(document.querySelectorAll(".one, .three, .five").forEach(function(e){e.classList.toggle("dark-mode"),e.classList.contains("dark-mode"),e.style.transition="background-color 0.5s ease-in-out, filter 0.5s ease-in-out"}),element.querySelectorAll("img").forEach(function(e){element.classList.contains("dark-mode")?e.style.filter="brightness(0.5)":e.style.filter="brightness(1)"}),element.classList.contains("three")){var e=document.querySelector("#lights-off"),t=document.querySelector("#lights-on");e.style.display="block",t.style.display="none"}}

Comment: I use this code in javacript I have here 3 images that I want to make smootly like the color and background color for them I used the answer of the another guy in this post.
  else if (element.classList.contains("three")) {
                var lightsOff = document.querySelector("#lights-off");
                var lightsOn = document.querySelector("#lights-on");
                var blackmoon = document.querySelector(".moon");
                lightsOff.style.display = "block";
                lightsOn.style.display = "none";
                blackmoon.style.display = "block";}